# Show that $[0,1]$ is a completion of $(0,1)\cap\mathbb Q$

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

How would I show that $[0,1]$ is a completion of $(0,1)\cap\mathbb Q$, where both are regarded as metric subspaces of $\mathbb R$ with its usual metric?

I found this question in an old past paper and I'm not sure how I would go about answering it.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, and $0,1$ are limits points of $(0,1)$...

Comment: Identity is an isometric embedding of $(0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ into $[0,1]$ and is dense because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ under standard norm